# PyQT5 не срабатываем присвоение значения переменной из QComboBox: "NameError: name 'sbrf' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

при обработке этого кода выходит ошибка NameError: name 'sbrf' is not defined

Я совсем запуталась, с чем это может быть связано

```
import sys
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QComboBox, QPushButton, QGridLayout)

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        import mysql.connector
        from mysql.connector import errorcode
        self.ee_param = {'host': '....', 'user': '....', 'password': '...', 'database': '...' }
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(**self.ee_param)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        ### создаем сетку
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setSpacing(10)

        ### первый раскрывающийся список
        self.cb_price = QComboBox()
        self.cb_price.addItems(['Будем считать потребителя?'] + ['Считать нового потребителя', 'Считать существующего потребителя'])
        ...
        self.grid.addWidget(self.cb_price, 0, 0)

        ### общие для всех списки
        rf = set()
        _sql = 'select region from gp'
        self.cursor.execute(_sql)
        for i in self.cursor.fetchall():
            rf.add(i[0])
        self.cb_rf = QComboBox()
        self.cb_rf.addItems(['Выберите регион'] + list(rf))

        self.grid.addWidget(self.cb_rf, 1, 0)
        self.cb_rf.setVisible(False)
        self.setLayout(self.grid)

        ### создаем кнопки активации
        self.cb_price.activated.connect(self.handleActivated_price)

        ### создаем кнопки активации для временно невидимых
        self.cb_rf.activated.connect(self.handleActivated_rf)

    def handleActivated_price(self, index):
        parametr = self.cb_price.itemText(index)
        if parametr == 'Считать нового потребителя':
            self.cb_rf.setVisible(True)
            gp = []
            _sql = 'select supplier_ee from gp where region like %s'
            self.cursor.execute(_sql, (sbrf,))
            for i in self.cursor.fetchall():
                gp.append(i[0])
           ...
        else:
            self.cb_rf.setVisible(True)
            consumers = []
            _sql = 'select Consumer_Name from consumers where region like %s'
            self.cursor.execute(_sql, (self.sbrf,))
            for i in self.cursor.fetchall():
                consumers.append(i[0])
            ...

    def handleActivated_rf(self, index):
        self.sbrf = self.cb_rf.itemText(index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if not QApplication.instance():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QApplication.instance()
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, у вас ошибка в этой строке:

```
self.cursor.execute(_sql, (sbrf,))
```

И в ней скорее всего ожидалось не `sbrf`, а `self.sbrf` как и в других строках:

```
self.cursor.execute(_sql, (self.sbrf,))
```

---

**PS.** советую вам быть осторожнее с `self.sbrf`, т.к. это поле появляется у объекта при выполнении `handleActivated_rf` а используется в других местах. Т.е. если у вас метод будет вызван `handleActivated_price` до `handleActivated_rf` получите ошибку вида `AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'sbrf'`.

Например, вы можете в конструкторе `__init__` добавить строчку `self.sbrf = None`.

---

**UPD.**

Заметил, что у автора возникла путаница с атрибутами, поэтому приложу весь код с исправлением:

```
import enum

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QComboBox, QGridLayout

import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

# NOTE: Лучше более осмысленное дать название
class CbPriceEnum(enum.Enum):
    NEW = enum.auto()
    CURRENT = enum.auto()


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ee_param = {'host': '....', 'user': '....', 'password': '...', 'database': '...'}
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(**self.ee_param)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        ### создаем сетку
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setSpacing(10)

        ### первый раскрывающийся список
        self.cb_price = QComboBox()
        self.cb_price.addItem('Будем считать потребителя?')  # NOTE: я так понимаю, это значение будет не выбираемым
        self.cb_price.addItem('Считать нового потребителя', userData=CbPriceEnum.NEW)
        self.cb_price.addItem('Считать существующего потребителя', userData=CbPriceEnum.CURRENT)
        ...
        self.grid.addWidget(self.cb_price, 0, 0)

        ### общие для всех списки

        _sql = 'select region from gp'
        self.cursor.execute(_sql)
        rf = {i[0] for i in self.cursor.fetchall()}

        self.cb_rf = QComboBox()
        self.cb_rf.addItems(['Выберите регион'] + list(rf))
        self.cb_rf.setVisible(False)

        self.grid.addWidget(self.cb_rf, 1, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.grid)

        self.cb_price.activated.connect(self.handleActivated_price)
        self.cb_rf.activated.connect(self.handleActivated_rf)

    def handleActivated_price(self, index):
        # NOTE: В коде из вопроса этот комбобокс всегда показывался
        # NOTE: Всегда показываем, мб сюда добавится условие, что показываем только 'Считать нового потребителя'
        self.cb_rf.setVisible(True)

    def handleActivated_rf(self, index):
        sbrf = self.cb_rf.itemText(index)

        # NOTE: текст может поменяться, поэтому проверяем по данным элемента, используя перечисление
        parametr = self.cb_price.itemData(index)
        if parametr == CbPriceEnum.NEW:
            _sql = 'select supplier_ee from gp where region like %s'
            self.cursor.execute(_sql, (sbrf,))
            gp = [i[0] for i in self.cursor.fetchall()]
            ...
        else:
            _sql = 'select Consumer_Name from consumers where region like %s'
            self.cursor.execute(_sql, (sbrf,))
            consumers = [i[0] for i in self.cursor.fetchall()]
            ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if not QApplication.instance():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QApplication.instance()
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Т.е. если у вас метод будет вызван handleActivated_price до handleActivated_rf получите ошибку вида AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'sbrf'.  Почему возникает эта ошибка?

Comment: @Gaillardinija, потому что атрибут sbrf создастся в handleActivated_rf когда вы ему присвоили значение `self.sbrf = ...`

Comment: Да, в handleActivated_price  у меня становится видимым self.cb_rf, я выбираю элемент, происходит connect и присвоение self.sbrf выбранного значения, но дальше handleActivated_rf это значение не идет и возникает AttributeError. Я полагала, оно должно было стать доступно и handleActivated_price после этого

Comment: @Gaillardinija, не понимаю вас, напишите текст `AttributeError` там указано с каким атрибутом беда

Comment: Простите, я учусь и путаюсь в понятиях. Ошибка следующая: AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'sbrf'

Comment: И стек трассы указывает на строку внутри метода handleActivated_price?

Comment: Да, ошибка в  handleActivated_price при попытке подставить значение в sql запрос

Comment: @Gaillardinija, обновил ответ, думаю станет немного понятнее

Comment: Спасибо, пока это не работает, возможно, мне надо время подумать о том, что такое атрибута класса и атрибут экземпляра класса?

Comment: @Gaillardinija, мое исправление должно было избавить вас от ошибки с тем атрибутом. Давай еще раз: сначала нужно выбрать значение в `self.cb_rf`, тогда `self.cb_rf` получит значение, потом нужно выбрать значение `self.cb_price`, тогда вызовется `handleActivated_price` и значение `self.cb_rf` будет использоваться в SQL запросе

Comment: Сначала выбирается self.cb_price, вызывается handleActivated_price, оттуда нажимается на self.cb_rf и выбранное значение должно быть дальше использовано в handleActivated_price

Comment: @Gaillardinija, наоборот ведь должно быть. Вы не можете использовать значение self.cb_rf пока это самое значение не получите (либо адаптируйте ваш код чтобы он SQL формировал без фильтра с `region`, раз self.cb_rf еще не задан). Подумайте снова над порядком действий. И предлагаю закончить обсуждение, т.к. оно не связанно с темой вашего вопросом, на которое я уже дал ответ (вы можете, например, создать новый вопрос по вашей архитектуре). У вас ведь нет теперь ошибки `“NameError: name 'sbrf' is not defined”`?

Comment: Спасибо, но я полагала, значение должно быть получено по клику. Хорошо, еще раз спасибо за помочь с решением проблемы поиска атрибута

Comment: @Gaillardinija, вы про `self.cb_rf.setVisible(True)`? Я не сразу понял про какой клик вы говорили. Видите ли, та строка выполняет в момент выбора `self.cb_price`, а значит *всегда* выполняется до `handleActivated_rf`. Поэтому, как и писал выше, нужно продумать архитектуру. Т.е. делайте так: логику работы с базой убирайте из `handleActivated_price` и переносите в `handleActivated_rf`. А в `handleActivated_price` оставьте только управление видимостью второго комбобокса. Тогда будет логично выглядеть

Comment: @Gaillardinija, не влезло в предыдущий комментарий... Могу обновить пример из ответа, чтобы показать, что имел ввиду. И кст если я вам помог, то [проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, так изначально и делала, но потом решила поменять логику и поняла, что результаты сюда никак не падают, да буду переосмысливать архитектуру, еще раз спасибо большое! Обновите, если есть возможность, думаю взгляд со стороны лишним не будет

Comment: @Gaillardinija, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за enum, раньше не знала об этом

Comment: @Gaillardinija, пожалуйста, удачи :)